# Downshift + react-window + material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, downshift

> **EDIT**: I strongly recommend using the [new Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete) that has a multitude of options and works very well instead of integrating
> Downshift manually.

I've tried to adapt [this downshift example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kentcdodds/downshift-examples/tree/master/?module=%2Fsrc%2Fother-examples%2Freact-window&moduleview=1) (`other-examples/react-window`) to work with material-ui components.

I've tried several options in my local environment but it breaks the rendering when scrolling or navigating the results with the keyboard. I've forked the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/300owpxnxq?module=%2Fsrc%2Fother-examples%2Freact-window&moduleview=1). The only code I've adapted is the `ItemRenderer` function, changing the original `Item` by `ListItem` or `MenuItem` but the result is the same. I also adapted FixedSizeList's `itemSize` to `46` to match the material-ui component height, but it doesn't fix anything.

I don't quite understand why the [material-ui list example](https://next.material-ui.com/demos/lists/#virtualized-list) works with [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) but it breaks with [downshift](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift).

Any help would be appreciated :)

Versions used:

```
@material-ui/core: 3.9.3
downshift: 3.1.8
react-window: 1.8.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it, I missed the `style={this.props.style}` that was passed to the `ListItem` component in the material-ui example and apparently that was breaking everything...

I adapted the whole example with material-ui components, in case it's useful to someone.